# Unable to update MYSQL database table fields using php in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, xampp

So, I am trying to design a `php` website, and so far it works well in terms of adding an entry to the list table.

The problem is, it isnt able to **update** the table using `edit.php`. When the edit link is clicked it shows a message:

> "There is no data to be edited."

But if I try to manually put `localhost/edit.php**?id=1**` it shows the id numbered list and works fine. Please help.

**home.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first PHP Website</title>
    </head>
   <?php
   session_start(); //starts the session
   if($_SESSION['user']){ // checks if the user is logged in  
   }
   else{
      header("location: index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in
   }
   $user = $_SESSION['user']; //assigns user value
   ?>
    <body>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>

<hello>! 
 <!--Display's user name-->
        <a href="logout.php">Click here to go logout</a><br/><br/>
        <form action="add.php" method="POST">
           Add more to list: <input type="text" name="details" /> <br/>
           Public post? <input type="checkbox" name="public[]" value="yes" /> <br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Add to list"/>
        </form>
    <h2 align="center">My list</h2>
    <table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Post Time</th>
      <th>Edit Time</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Public Post</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database");
      $query = mysql_query("select * from list");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
        print "<tr>";
          print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
          print '<td align="center">'. $row['details'] . "</td>";
          print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_posted'] . " - " . $row['time_posted'] . "</td>";
          print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_edited'] . " - " . $row['time_edited'] . "</td>";
          print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php">edit</a></td>';
          print '<td align="center"><a href="delete.php">delete</a></td>';
          print '<td align="center">'. $row['public'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
      }
    ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image])

**edit.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first PHP website</title>
    </head>
    <?php
    session_start(); //starts the session
    if($_SESSION['user']){ //checks if user is logged in
    }
    else{
        header("location:index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in
    }
    $user = $_SESSION['user']; //assigns user value
    $id_exists = false;
    ?>
    <body>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Hello <?php Print "$user"?>!</p> <!--Displays user's name-->
        <a href="logout.php">Click here to logout</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="home.php">Return to Home page</a>
        <h2 align="center">Currently Selected</h2>
        <table border="1px" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Post Time</th>
                <th>Edit Time</th>
                <th>Public Post</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                if(!empty($_GET['id']))
                {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    $id_exists = true;
                    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
                    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //connect to database
                    $query = mysql_query("Select * from list Where id='$id'"); // SQL Query
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if($count > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            Print "<tr>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['details'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_posted']. " - ". $row['time_posted']."</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_edited']. " - ". $row['time_edited']. "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['public']. "</td>";
                            Print "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $id_exists = false;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <?php
        if($id_exists)
        {
        Print '
        <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
            Enter new detail: <input type="text" name="details"/><br/>
            public post? <input type="checkbox" name="public[]" value="yes"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Update List"/>
        </form>
        ';
        }
        else
        {
            Print '<h2 align="center">There is no data to be edited.</h2>';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
        mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
        $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
        $public = "no";
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $time = strftime("%X");//time
        $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");//date
        foreach($_POST['public'] as $list)
        {
            if($list != null)
            {
                $public = "yes";
            }
        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE list SET details='$details', public='$public', date_edited='$date', time_edited='$time' WHERE id='$id'") ;
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>
```

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/m8dloz7d7/screenshot_20.png]

and here's the one with `?id=1` in the url
http;//s15,postimg,org/yoabiq0p7/screenshot_21,png (change the commas with fullstops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing only the edit.php, you need to print the entire edit link.

```
print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php">edit</a></td>';
```

Replace this line with:

```
print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">edit</a></td>';
```

This will solve the problem.

P.S: Be careful, your code is open for SQL Injection! Make sure to use mysql_real_escape_string() in this place:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

If the id is only number, you can do the following too to avoid SQL Injection:

```
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);
```

The SQL Injection thing is very serious and you need to filter what comes from outside. I recommend using prepared statement PDO too.

Answer (score 0):

you arent passing the data in the home.php

you are doing normal link to edit.php and you arent passing the data ?id=1

try edit this:

```
print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php">edit</a></td>';
```

to this:

```
print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row . '">edit</a></td>';
```